# Combinations and permutations help

Tags: permutations, combinations

In how many ways can 4 women and 3 men be arranged in a circle? In how many ways 
can this be done if the tallest woman and shortest man must be next to each other? Ans: 240

I did the first question and got 720 (6!), but I do not get the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$5!\times 2$=240. You bound the tallest woman and the shortest man together and view them as one person and do permutation. We have $5!$. Since the tallest woman can be the left or the right hand side of the man. So, we have 2 variants for each permutation. Hence, the total number is $5!\times 2$.